# Sympy комплексные ответы в уравнении

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

Код:

```
ex = Eq(simplify('cos(pi/3 - x)'), simplify('1/2'))
solveset(ex, domain=S.Reals)
```

(В интерактивном режиме) ответ:

```
Union(ImageSet(Lambda(_n, 2*_n*pi + atan(sqrt(3)*(2*re(sqrt(-(-1)**(1/3))*exp(-I*pi/3)) + 1)/(1 - 2*sqrt(3)*im(sqrt(-(-1)**(1/3))*exp(-I*pi/3))))), S.Integers), ImageSet(Lambda(_n, 2*_n*pi + atan(sqrt(3)*(1 - 2*re(sqrt(-(-1)**(1/3))*exp(-I*pi/3)))/(2*sqrt(3)*im(sqrt(-(-1)**(1/3))*exp(-I*pi/3)) + 1)) + pi), S.Integers))
```

Тут есть различные мнимые единицы. Я указал домен (хз как по-русски правильно называть) как R. Что мне сделать, чтобы в ответе были только реальные числа?

Comment: что вы думаете `re()` делает?

Comment: @jfs, она делает почти то, что мне нужно. Но как "вогнать" в эту функцию union?

Comment: @jfs сделал так: 
`a = solveset(ex, domain=S.Reals)
re(next(iter(a)))`
Но не помогло:
`atan(sqrt(3)*(2*re(sqrt(-(-1)**(1/3))*exp(-I*pi/3)) + 1)/(1 - 2*sqrt(3)*im(sqrt(-(-1)**(1/3))*exp(-I*pi/3))))
`

Comment: @vladF Может так оказаться что хотя фигурирует внутри в выражении комплексные величины, при этом результат может быть вещественным?

Comment: добавлять не нужно, re уже в формуле в вопросе присутствует. Вы уже запросили domain=Reals.

Comment: @vladF Я для вашего примера получил [вот такой ответ](https://image.prntscr.com/image/nQylgDdETk6GPo0QviTbCQ.png) в символьном виде. Судя по нём он полностью вещественный действительный по значению, т.к. берутся re/im т.е. действительная и мнимая части от комплексных формул, а эти части просто вещественные уже а не комплексные, так что ваш ответ весь вещественный а не комплексный.

Answer (score 1):

Я вашу формулу-ответ распечатал в красивой форме и получил вот что

[image: формула-ответ в красивой форме]

Как можно заметить в формуле используются фигурные `R`, `I`, это действительная и мнимая часть от комплексных чисел (`re`, `im` в формуле-ответе у автора), это означает что хотя число комплексное, но от него берётся только действительная часть в числителе (`re`) и мнимая часть в знаменателе (`im`), а эти обе части они вещественные уже а не комплексные. Т.е. другими словами берётся арктангенс от вещественного числа и вся формула в итоге вещественная, а не комплексная, не смотря на то что в ней фигурируют комплексные числа.

Я на Wolfram Alpha упростил комплексное выражение в скобках и [получил вот что](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(-pow(-1,%201%2F3))%2Aexp(-i%2Api%2F3)), читайте пункт Alternate Form: действительная часть получилась `-1/2`, а мнимая часть `-sqrt(3)/2`.

Кстати Wolfram Alpha выдала [более простые решения](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos(pi%2F3%20-%20x)%20%3D%201%2F2) исходной задачи: `x = 2 * pi * n` и `x = 2 * pi * n + 2/3 * pi`.

Comment: Это понятно, но как сделать ответ таки? Пользователям не объяснить того, что это нормально

Comment: @vladF Нужно просто то что в скобках после re и im (там одинаковое выражение) перевести в комплексную форму (возможно вручную) и взять у этой формы действительную (для re) и мнимую часть (для im) и тогда получится полностью вещественное (не комплексное) представление. Либо если достаточно приблизительного решения то можно всё значение арктангенса перевести в численную приблизительную форму (для этого есть функция N у библиотеки sympy), получится обычное вещественное число.

Comment: @vladF Вот я на Вольфрам Альфе упростил выражение комплексное в скобках [получил вот что](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(-pow(-1,+1%2F3))*exp(-i*pi%2F3)), там в пункте Alternate Form можно видеть что действительная часть `-1/2`, а мнимая часть `-sqrt(3)/2`.